Is there any way to use Lodash in node.js without installing any npm packages?
I tried way too much things, and all of them failed:
const _ = require('lodash');
import _ from 'lodash';
import 'lodash';
const _ = require('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js');
import _ from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js';
import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js';

The answer is definitely something simple, yet I couldn't find it anywhere after half an hour of searching. What am I doing wrong?

Why don't you want to install it?

it's for a github repository with my advent of code solutions. i don't feel like installing npm packages that i only use in one single file out of the 25.

you can simply copy the lodash.min.js file in your project

Lodash provides an ESM build, which is available via CDN: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/lodash-es. You can import this module dynamically, but you will have to use a custom HTTPS loader, as Node.js (as of version 22) does not support import from HTTPS out of the box.
// https-loader.js
export const load = async (url, context, nextLoad) => {
  if (url.startsWith("https://")) {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    return {
      format: "module",
      shortCircuit: true,
      source: await res.text(),
    };
  }
  return nextLoad(url);
};

// lodash-test.js
import _ from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash-es@4.17.21/lodash.min.js";

console.log(_.defaults({ a: 1 }, { a: 3, b: 2 }));

Then execute with:
$ node --import 'data:text/javascript,import { register } from "node:module"; import { pathToFileURL } from "node:url"; register(pathToFileURL("./https-loader.js"));' ./lodash-test.js  
{ a: 1, b: 2 }

If you want to use HTTPS imports with Node.js for whatever reason, make sure to research security implications.
